# Androidplot: How can have integer data labels?

Tags: androidplot

This is probably very simple, but I cannot find it in the online documentation.
I have a data plot with integer range values on a floating point domain (Integer function of time). Using

```
plot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));
```

I obtain integer labels on the side of the graph. But I still get one decimal place in the label on the data points instead of integers, e.g. "100.0".
How can I obtain integer values only, e.g. "100" ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this:

- If you want data with floating point—i.e., `100.0`—then **DELETE** that line `plot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));` from your code.
- If you just want integer data—i.e., `100`—then **keep** (include) that line `plot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));` in your code.